# Should all API calls be asynchronous in React?

Tags: reactjs

When making API calls in React, should they all be asynchronous?

Is this a one-size-fits-all answer, or is this scenario-based? If so, what are some good examples of where to use async calls, and where not to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to perform sync API calls is by using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) in [a very particular fashion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#synchronous_request) which was deprecated a long time ago.

More modern APIs like [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) do not support sync requests even as 1st April joke.

So, yes, it's a very good idea to keep your API requests async, always.

Sync requests are problematic, make your app perform *really* bad & are just conceptually silly.